# Python: how to extract string from file - only once

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the below output from router stored in a file

```
-#- --length-- -----date/time------ path

 3     97103164 Feb 7 2016 01:36:16 +05:30 taas/NN41_R11_Golden_Image
 4         1896 Sep 27 2019 14:22:08 +05:30 taas/NN41_R11_Golden_Config
 5         1876 Nov 27 2017 20:07:50 +05:30 taas/nfast_default.cfg
```

I want to search for substring `'Golden_Image'` from the file & get the complete path. So here, the required output would be this string:

```
taas/NN41_R11_Golden_Image
```

**First attempt:**

```
import re 
with open("outlog.out") as f:
    for line in f:
         if  "Golden_Image" in  line:
            print(line)
```

Output:

```
3 97103164 Feb 7 2016 01:36:16 +05:30 taas/NN41_R11_Golden_Image
```

**Second attempt**

```
import re
hand = open('outlog.out')
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall('.*?Golden_Image.*?',line)
    if len(x) > 0:
         print x
```

Output:

```
['3 97103164 Feb 7 2016 01:36:16 +05:30 taas/NN41_R11_Golden_Image']
```

Neither of these give the required output. How can I fix this?

Comment: can you attached the file you are reading?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually surprisingly fiddly to do if the path can contain spaces.
You need to use the maxsplit argument to `split` to identify the path field.

```
with open("outlog.out") as f:
    for line in f:
         field = line.split(None,7)
         if "Golden_Image" in field:
            print(field)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do split on the line and check for the "Golden_Image" string exists in the splitted parts.

```
import re 
with open("outlog.out") as f:
    for line in f:
         if not "Golden_Image" in i:
             continue
         print re.search(r'\S*Golden_Image\S*', line).group()
```

or

```
images = re.findall(r'\S*Golden_Image\S*', open("outlog.out").read())
```

*Example*:

```
>>> s = '''
-#- --length-- -----date/time------ path

 3     97103164 Feb 7 2016 01:36:16 +05:30 taas/NN41_R11_Golden_Image
 4         1896 Sep 27 2019 14:22:08 +05:30 taas/NN41_R11_Golden_Config
 5         1876 Nov 27 2017 20:07:50 +05:30 taas/nfast_default.cfg'''.splitlines()
>>> for line in s:
    for i in line.split():
        if  "Golden_Image" in i:
            print i


taas/NN41_R11_Golden_Image
>>>
```

Comment: You could probably use regex without needing to split and compare every single split part.

Comment: **Thanks for the answer Avinash

However single line command is erroring**

`images = re.findall(r'\S*Golden_Image\S*', open("outlog.out").read())`

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Your answer is basically correct, but I found it a bit confusing to read because the "example" isn't actually an example of the two proposed approaches.  The approach used in the example is actually the clearest and most readable. I'd make that front and center, and put the rest as bonus material, if that.

Comment: post the full code.. Is this a .py script or .sh script

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett don't know what you mean by ""example" isn't actually an example of the two proposed approaches. "?

Comment: The first two bits of code use regex, and the one in the example doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Reading full content at once and then doing the search will not be efficient. Instead, file can be read line by line and if line matches the criteria then path can be extracted without doing further split and using RegEx.

Use following RegEx to get path

```
\s+(?=\S*$).*
```

Link: https://regex101.com/r/zuH0Zv/1

Here if working code:

```
import re
data = "3     97103164 Feb 7 2016 01:36:16 +05:30 taas/NN41_R11_Golden_Image"
regex = r"\s+(?=\S*$).*"
test_str = "3     97103164 Feb 7 2016 01:36:16 +05:30 taas/NN41_R11_Golden_Image"
matches = re.search(regex, test_str)
print(matches.group().strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow you code, if you just want get the right output, you can more simple.

```
with open("outlog.out") as f:
    for line in f:
         if  "Golden_Image" in  line:
            print(line.split(" ")[-1])
```

the output is :

```
taas/NN41_R11_Golden_Image
```

PS： if you want some more complex operations, you may need try the `re` module like the @Avinash Raj answered.